# Boilerplate not starting in Windows 10 + Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: node.js, exit, status, react-boilerplate

I'm use: node: v10.16
npm: 6.9

```
react-boilerplate@4.0.0 start H:\count
cross-env NODE_ENV=development node server

'cross-env' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-boilerplate@4.0.0 start: cross-env NODE_ENV=development node server
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-boilerplate@4.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-10-24T07_43_09_568Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install cross-env so that you can use it: `npm i -g cross-env`